# NSMatrix and Push buttons from IB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to create a group of buttons that behave like radio group created from IB. 
I read from [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Matrix/Concepts/MatrixSelectionModes.html) that i can do that using NSRadioModeMatrix but i don't know how  to insert buttons in a matrix via IB.

If it would't possible could you kindly guide me in this operation with programmatically ?
(i also ask you :it is possible to add buttons via IB and only NSMatrix via code ? ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an `NSMatrix` in Interface Builder, but you don't do it by dragging one from the Objects palette.

What you do is select all of your buttons, and then choose either the `Editor > Embed In > Matrix` menu item (Xcode 4) or `Layout > Embed Objects In > Matrix` menu item (Interface Builder 3).